# rospy function scheduler

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is there a ropsy scheduler for calling a function after a period of time (or periodically calling it every n secs). The python sched module is kind of misbehaving, I guess it conflicts with ros based on the following example using the ps joystick with the PR2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('d3')
import rospy
import sched, time
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy

class Joystick(object):
    def __init__(self, topic_name='/joy'):
        self.topic_name = topic_name
        self.buttons_names = {'l1':10, 'l2':8}
        self.sub = rospy.Subscriber(topic_name, Joy, self.cb)
        self.blocked = False
        self.sched = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
        print '>>> press L1 button'
       
    def cb(self, data):
        print '>> in callback:', data.buttons[self.buttons_names['l1']], data.buttons[self.buttons_names['l2']]
        if not self.blocked:
            self.foo(data)
    
    def foo(self, data):
        print '>> in foo:', data.buttons[self.buttons_names['l1']], data.buttons[self.buttons_names['l2']]
        if data.buttons[self.buttons_names['l1']]:
            self.blocked = True
            rospy.loginfo('%d', data.buttons[self.buttons_names['l1']])
            rospy.loginfo('L1 pressed')
            self.sched.enter(1, 1, self.bar, ())
        self.sched.run()
        
    def bar(self):
        rospy.loginfo('resuming control')
        self.blocked = False
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    rospy.init_node('foo', anonymous=False)
    joy = Joystick()
    rospy.spin()
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35452/rospy-function-scheduler/) by [Yianni](https://answers.ros.org/users/215/yianni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2012-06-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A [Timer](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Time#Timer) should do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yianni](https://answers.ros.org/users/215/yianni/) on 2012-06-01**:
Thanks. Works like a charm.